# Wrong type of error when testing javascript function

Tags: javascript, unit-testing

I am trying to test the following code:

```
  /** ABSTRACT METHOD PLACEHOLDER */
MyResult.prototype.get = throwNotImplementedError;

function throwNotImplementedError(resultId) {
    throw new NotImplementedError('Please implement in Item Groups and Items. This call is abstract');
}
```

with the following test.

```
it('should have a placeholder for get', function(){
    expect(function(){return MyResult.get(123);}).toThrowError(NotImplementedError);
});
```

What ends up happenining is that a TypeError is thrown instead of my custom NotImplementedError. The type error's message is: "MyResult.get is not a function".

I'm wondering if it might have something to do with calling the variable in the prototype 'get' but I think I've seen examples like this where they name javascript classes and use a custom method that they call get. It seems to work for other calls.

Do you have any advice on why it doesn't work for this call?

Comment: Just for reference to anyone else. SLaks and Tao let me know that prototype only works with instantiated classes. In order to be able to use the method as a 'class method' I would have to exclude the term prototype and make sure I call it with the name. e.g. declare it MyResult.get = function(){...}; and use it like MyResult.get();

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**It's a prototype function**

So you have to test `get` function with an instance of an object like this:

```
it('should have a placeholder for get', function(){
    var resultObj = new MyResult(); // Create an instance of your object
    expect(function(){return resultObj.get(123);}).toThrowError(NotImplementedError);
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. So let say I want the Class to have static methods that would basically be used like a factory that creates a MyResult Object (or a list of MyResult Objects) how would I create it? would I just exclude the word prototype?

Comment: When you implement a function in a prototype object, it's not meant to be static. It's an OOP-like method of a class (in your case, `MyResult` acts like a class).

Answer (score 4):

The error is completely correct.

You defined `MyResult.prototype.get`, which has nothing to do with `MyResult.get`.

You probably want to create an instance.

Comment: Thanks! maybe you could clarify a little bit if you have time. I assumed prototypical inheritence would make it so that MyResult.get (if it did not have anything) would look to the prototype and find that MyResult.prototype.get has a method, thus using that. Could you fix my misstep in thinking?

Comment: @ThinkBonobo: No.  Prototype inheritance works for class _instances_ (eg, `new MyResult()`.  `MyResult` itself is an instance of `Function`, and inherits its prototype.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. I'll have to figure out another way to throw my 'factory methods' into my code then.